# What is k(T) related to the elliptic curve and how this can be evaluated?

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-equations

In this paper, The 1729 K3 Surface, the link is here https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00735, Ken Ono writes

In particular, parametrized solutions to $X^3 + Y^3 = Z^3 + W^3$ give us families of
elliptic curves with rank at least two. Ramanujan gave us such solutions in (1). He means the
Ramanujan's identity $$(3a^2 + 5ab - 5b^2)^3 + (4a^2 - 4ab + 6b^2)^3 + (5a^2 - 5ab - 3b^2)^3 = (6a^2 - 4ab + 4b^2)^3$$

Let
 \begin{equation*}
 \begin{aligned}
 P1 &= (x_1(T ), y_1(T )) = (6T^2 - 4T + 4,\hspace{1mm} -3T^2 - 5T + 5)\\
 P2 &= (x_2(T ), y_2(T )) = (4T^2 - 4T + 6, \hspace{2mm} 5T^2 - 5T - 3)
 \end{aligned}
 \end{equation*}

and $$k(T ) = 63(3T^2 - 3T + 1)(T^2 + T + 1)(T^2 - 3T + 3)$$

Then $$x_1(T)^3 + y_1(T)^3 = k(T ) = x_2(T)^3 + y_2(T)^3$$.

It is clear that Ramanujan's identity gives the solution. But what is k(T)? It looks discriminant. 
How this can be calculated in this case?

Comment: Which is exactly the question? We have a definition for $k(T)$. So $k(T)$ *is* (by definition) given by the formula from the OP, and there is furthermore the relation$$x_1(T)^3 + y_1(T)^3 = k(T) = x_2(T)^3 + y_2(T)^3 \ .$$ The usage of the word *discriminant* makes the question even less digestible. Maybe the intended question gets some shape when we see the attempts to solve it.